# Are Google Volley HTTP requests synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: android, asynchronous, httprequest, android-volley, synchronous

so i had a interesting conversation today about Volley being synchronous. So i want to ask you if the Volley HTTP-requests synchronous or asynchronous. It's about the HTTP-Requests, not the fact being an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standpoint of the code telling Volley to make a request, the API is asynchronous. You provide a callback, and you get the results or error asynchronously via that callback.

Other HTTP client APIs, like OkHttp, offer either synchronous or asynchronous operation.

Comment: So out of the box these calls are asynchronous? Do you know if there is a source from google or an official page where they tell it?

Comment: @LukasS: "So out of the box these calls are asynchronous?" -- yes. "Do you know if there is a source from google or an official page where they tell it?" -- it is obvious from the API. You are certainly welcome to read [the Volley documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) and [the Volley source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley).

Comment: Ah okay thank you very much :) These were the answers i've been looking for.